# Need help adding animation to SVG graphic

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have the following code for a SVG graphic:

```html
<script>

</script>

<body>
    <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='200' height='200'>
    <rect x = '0', y = '0', height = '200' width = '200' color = 'yellow' fill = 'yellow'></rect>
    <line x1 = '0', y1 = '0', x2 = '200', y2 = '200', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'>
        <animateMotion begin='0s' dur='5s' values='0,0; 40,0' repeatCount='indefinite'></animateMotion>
    </line>
    <line x1 = '200', y1 = '0', x2 = '0', y2 = '200', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '0', y1 = '40', x2 = '200', y2 = '160', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '0', y1 = '160', x2 = '200', y2 = '40', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '0', y1 = '120', x2 = '200', y2 = '80', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '0', y1 = '80', x2 = '200', y2 = '120', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '0', y1 = '80', x2 = '200', y2 = '120', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '40', y1 = '0', x2 = '160', y2 = '200', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '80', y1 = '0', x2 = '120', y2 = '200', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '120', y1 = '0', x2 = '80', y2 = '200', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
    <line x1 = '160', y1 = '0', x2 = '40', y2 = '200', style = 'stroke:black; stroke-width:1'></line>
</svg>

</body>


</html>
```

What I want to do is to make each line rotate clockwise to the position of the next line. I tried using animateMotion, but the line doesn't rotate, just moves itself linear. How can I make the lines rotate? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateTransform has an example showing something rotating.

Comment: Thank you, but can I use animateTransform for a line? And how do I set up the coordinates?

Comment: Yes, you can use if for on any shape in SVG. Find the centre of the line.

Comment: Use `<animateTransform begin='0s' dur='5s' from='0,100,100' to="360,100,100" repeatCount='indefinite' attributeName="transform" type="rotate"></animateTransform>`